# How to read and print float data from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I tried this code and wanted to print some data from a JSON file. I want to extract just the data from `mOrientation`, `mLocalVelocity`, and `mLocalAcceleration`. I need the data in `float`.
This is file:

```
{
"motionAndDeviceRelated":{
    "mOrientation":[-0.00512593,-0.960999,-1.76169e-06],
    "mLocalVelocity":[0,0,0],
    "mWorldVelocity":[0,0,0],
    "mAngularVelocity":[0,0,0],
    "mLocalAcceleration":[0,0,0],
    "mWorldAcceleration":[0,0,0],
    "mExtentsCentre":[0,0.643195,-0.08594]
  },
  "carDamage":{
    "mCrashState":0,
    "mAeroDamage":0,
    "mEngineDamage":0.00078094
  }
}
```

This is the code:

```
import json

telemetry_file=open('C:/Users/szabo/Desktop/CREST2/crest2_formatted.json', 'r')
telemetry_data=telemetry_file.read()
obj=json.loads(telemetry_data)

for i in obj['motionAndDeviceRelated']:
    print(i)
```

And I get only this:

```
mOrientation
mLocalVelocity
mWorldVelocity
mAngularVelocity
mLocalAcceleration
mWorldAcceleration
mExtentsCentre
```

Comment: ```for k, v in obj['motionAndDeviceRelated'].items(): print(k, v)```

Comment: You are looping a dictionary, try `for key,value in obj['motionAndDeviceRelated'].items()`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to print only mOrientation, mLocalVelocity and mLocalAcceleration? Without the for

Comment: You can use `obj['motionAndDeviceRelated']['mOrientation']` outside a loop to access its data. The same for your other fields

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the values inside `obj['motionAndDeviceRelated]` by name. Something like

```
wanted_data = ['mOrientation', 'mLocalVelocity', 'mLocalAcceleration']
for field in wanted_data:
    data = obj['motionAndDeviceRelated'][field]
    print(field, ':', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in obj['motionAndDeviceRelated']:
    print(i)
```

This loop gets you only JSON keys. To fetch data you need to use this:

```
for i in obj['motionAndDeviceRelated']:
    print(i + " " obj['motionAndDeviceRelated'][i])
```

Comment: Why not like the comments?

Answer (score 1):

Since `obj['motionAndDeviceRelated']` is a dictionary, to get both keys and values, you should iterate over it like this :

```
for k,v in obj['motionAndDeviceRelated'].items():
    print(k,':',v)
```

Output :

```
mOrientation : [-0.00512593, -0.960999, -1.76169e-06]
mLocalVelocity : [0, 0, 0]
mWorldVelocity : [0, 0, 0]
mAngularVelocity : [0, 0, 0]
mLocalAcceleration : [0, 0, 0]
mWorldAcceleration : [0, 0, 0]
mExtentsCentre : [0, 0.643195, -0.08594]
```